# Delphi Datasnap-XE :How does one setup a filter pragmatically?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, datasnap

I am using the following code to setup DataSnap Connection pragmatically

```
procedure TConnectThreed.Execute;
var
    DataSnapCon : TSQLConnection;
    proxy       : TSystemRDMClient;
begin
  proxy       := nil;
  DataSnapCon := nil;
  try
    DataSnapCon := TSQLConnection.Create(nil);
    DataSnapCon.Connected := False;
    DataSnapCon.DriverName := 'DATASNAP';
    DataSnapCon.LoginPrompt := False;
    DataSnapCon.Params.Values['port'] :=  '211';
    DataSnapCon.Params.Values['HostName'] :=  DevicesAddr;
    // 
    // What code must be added here to setup a Zlib + PC1 +RSA Filter ?
    // 
    try
      DataSnapCon.Open;
      proxy := TSystemRDMClient.Create(DataSnapCon.DBXConnection);
```

**QUESTION:**

How do I setup a Zlib & PC1 & RSA filter pragmatically?

Comment: What is a `PC1 filter` ?

Comment: @Jeroen: have a look at  this link http://membres.multimania.fr/pc1/pc1.html

Comment: thanks for teaching me something new.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the `dfm` file you see what is going on with the magic Driver property in the Object Inspector. The selections you make are stored in `TSQLConnection.Params` for name Filters.

To add the filters you can do this.

```
DataSnapCon.Params.Values['Filters'] :=
  '{"ZLibCompression":{"CompressMoreThan":"1024"},'+
   '"PC1":{"Key":"LiveStrongLance!"}}';
```

But this will still get `Connection Closed Gracefully` that you have experienced here [Delphi XE – Datasnap Filter problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035085/delphi-xe-datasnap-filter-problems/5064667#5064667).