DataSnap Secure Connection TCP/IP
I've got here Delphi 10.4.2 with DataSnap Server and Client only using TCP/IP ( no HTTP or HTTPS ) . I did the most bare-bones Server and Client to test Transport Level Encryption . I guess I am not understanding how it should work.
On Server :

I have PC1 with above key .
And on the Client I have following line added to the TSQLConnection .
SQLConnection.Params.Add('Filters={"PC1": {"Key": "test"}}');

First Question : I expected that it would simply not connect because of mismatching Keys.
Second Question : if I add RSA Filter on top of this , since there is no Secret Key or anything I can input for RSA Filter how exactly does it work with the Client .
Third Question : I am adding Authentication Manager to the mix . The username and password is sent plain-text over the wire ? or is it Encrypted with PC1 in my case ?
Thank you.
UPDATE 1
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Filtering_DataSnap_Byte_Stream
"There is no need to associate filters at the client side, as they are automatically instantiated based on a handshake protocol between client and server. Hence it is important that the client code registers the filters before connecting to a filtered server either by adding the unit name to the uses clause or in an early stage, such as initialization time."
This I think answers Question 1 and probably Question 3. Client connects to the Server does the Handshake and if server uses Encryption supported by the Client it automatically uses it. If not supported by client then I guess It does not connect .

1st - Correct, 2nd - not sure, 3rd - Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035085/delphi-xe-datasnap-filter-problems?rq=2 posting, the last post from Bob Swart and you will need to read this if you have not already https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/OpenSSL

@TDC : but it connected without problems... 1st

@TDC : so basically it is enough to set PC1 and RSA on the Server and the Client uses this automatically . I hope that it also means if I have Authentication then the authentication with the Server itself happens with PC1 and RSA ...
